# Removing partial duplicates in one table

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, ms-access-2016

I ran a query wizard to identify duplicates. The table shows as the following.
Sorry for the link, my reputation is not high enough to place an image.

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G13sP.gif)

As you can see, there are duplicates.  I would like to ignore the "Source".  To me, it doesn't matter which source station they come from.  It is a duplicate as long as their first name, last name and student number matches exactly.

I want to get rid of the duplicates. It doesn't matter which record gets deleted but I need one of them gone.

For example, amy johnson can come from either station 1 or station 5 but one of them has to go.

There are two "brian"s and one "Brian" with the capital letter B. These three brians are still considered the same person.  I need two of them gone. It doesn't matter which brain gets deleted as long as there is a query that deletes two brians and keep one brian.

Char williams has two different IDs. Meaning, they are probably two different Char williams that happen to have the same name and living in the same State.  So they are not duplicates.

Is there any way to delete these duplicate records? I looked at the microsoft forum but it doesn't seem to resort to my specific problem.  I am new to access and trying to see what would be the best way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid to link images in your question. You should instead post a sample of you actual data, and the result data you want to get

To eliminate duplicates do a `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, StudentNum, State
FROM mytable
```

If you want to count the duplicates, do a `GROUP BY`, which will achieve the same results but with an aggregate function, `(COUNT)` in this case

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, StudentNum, State, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM mytable
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, StudentNum, State
```

The Upper/Lower case doesn't matter in Access, it consider them the same